# Echo new line from greped file

Tags: echo, newline

I'm trying to print some values from a log file, but the echo print all in one line, I just want to print every result on a new line.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Acessos do usuario"
echo "</title></head><body>"
echo "$(egrep 'kelsen.faria' /var/squid/logs/access_custom.log | awk '{ print "Data: " $1, "Usuario: " $9, "IP: " $4 }' | uniq)"
echo "</body></html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you using `echo` for that? just call the command `egrep ...` without using echo and it will have newlines. Otherwise there is not much you can do, once you wrap the call in `$(...)`.

Comment: This is supposed to be a squid cgi/script, I'm not a programmer as you can see. The way I found to display this output on the web page would be echo.
So, there is no way using echo this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `egrep` command without `echo`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Acessos do usuario"
echo "</title></head><body>"
egrep 'kelsen.faria' /var/squid/logs/access_custom.log | \
    awk '{ print "Data: " $1, "Usuario: " $9, "IP: " $4 }' | uniq
echo "</body></html>"
```

But appearantly you are using the output as HTML. The newlines won't help you much there. You have to use some html formatting. The simlest way would be to insert `<br>` tags:

```
egrep 'kelsen.faria' /var/squid/logs/access_custom.log | \
    awk '{ print "Data: " $1, "Usuario: " $9, "IP: " $4, "<br>" }' | uniq
```

Comment: without the "echo" nothing appears in the browser page.

Comment: it is still showing everything in just one line, maybe it need formatting on tables or something like.

Comment: Well, the echo is now printing newlines. But you are using it to create HTML code.. So newlines are ignored. You'd have to add the `<br>` tag after every data set.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it display correctly by using tables, I think I'll continue through this way.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Acessos do usuario"
echo "</title></head><body>"
echo "<table border="1">"
echo "<tr>"
echo "<th>Data</th>"
echo "<th>Usuario</th>"
echo "<th>IP</th>"
echo "</tr>"
echo "<tr>"
egrep 'kelsen.faria' /var/squid/logs/access_custom.log | \
    awk '{ print "<td>" $1, "</td>" "<td>" $9, "</td>" "<td>" $4 "</td>" "</tr>"
 }' | uniq
echo "</table>"
echo "</body></html>"
```